# Uploading files using HTML file input on iphone

Tags: xhtml, upload, input, iphone, xhtml-mp

I am creating a web form for uploading small movie clips to a HTTP server. However, while my HTML file input control gets shown on an ipod touch, the button is completely disabled and I cannot click it to upload files.

What do I have to do to use the input control to upload files (e.g. movie clips or pictures) to my HTTP server. My page is XHTML MP 1.2 compliant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A html5 web app for mobile safari to upload images from the Photos.app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IOS6 now allows it:
http://agileleague.com/blog/hidden-gem-of-ios6-file-uploads-in-mobile-safari/

I tested and it works. Cheers!