# Can you make an html form to upload images from cell phones with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, xhtml, image, upload

I have a website at which you can upload your photos from a trip, for example, and have them displayed in your profile. I am now trying to make a mobile version of this website. So my question is, what is the easiest way to make it possible for my users to upload their images from their cell phones to the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is client dependant so you can't do it work if client don't support it.

Comment: Well, some platforms are more important than others. Would it be possible to do it on the iPhone for example?

Comment: Take a look here if it can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577003/uploading-files-using-html-file-input-on-iphone